# Mobile APP stopped working

Tags: android

My mobile APP was working perfectly.
I got a new computer, downloaded `Eclipse` + `Android SDK`, and got the following error messages:

```
[2013-12-11 13:31:45 - MyPulse] ERROR: Unable to open class file C:\Users\dridley\Dropbox\MyPulse\Martin Brown\ideaProjects\MyPulse\gen\com\palczewski\mypulse\Manifest.java: Permission denied
[2013-12-11 13:36:04 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/json/simple/ItemList;
[2013-12-11 13:36:04 - MyPulse] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/json/simple/ItemList;
[2013-12-11 13:47:09 - MyPulse] Dx trouble writing output: already prepared
[2013-12-11 13:47:15 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/json/simple/ItemList;
[2013-12-11 13:47:15 - MyPulse] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/json/simple/ItemList;
```

The messages repeat many times.

Answer (score 1):

Your project has more than one jar with `org.json.simple.ItemList`. Remove the extra jars and rebuild.

Also, having the work area in a Dropbox folder likely isn't a good idea. If you need to back up or share code, use a real version control system.